# How to POST input field that are disabled/readonly with condition?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I am trying to make my input field disabled or readonly if a button is not yet pressed but I am having problems with posting/submitting it to the database after I added a condition which makes it disabled or readonly

```
    <form action="{{ route('amber.timestone.home.start', $task->id) }}" method="POST" class="align-center">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                            <td>
                                <input class="my-2" type="text" name="ref" value="{{ $task->ref }}"
                                    @if(empty($task->start))
                                        readonly
                                    @endif
                                >


public function startTask($id)
    {
        $user = Task::find($id);
        $user->start = Carbon::now();
        $user->save();
        return back();
    }
public function endTask($id, Request $request)
    {
        $user = Task::find($id);
        $user->end = Carbon::now();
        $start = Carbon::parse($user->start);
        $end = Carbon::parse($user->end);
$user->ref = request('ref');
        $user->remarks = request('remarks');
        $user->campaign = request('campaign');
        $user->type = request('type');
            $hours = $end->diffInHours($start);
            $minutes = $end->diffInMinutes($start);
            $seconds = $end->diffInSeconds($start);
            $user->duration = $hours . ':' . $minutes . ':' . $seconds;
            $user->update();
            return back();
        }
```

I tried adding hidden with the same names as for those who are with readonly condition still not working

Comment: what is exactly your problem?

Comment: You can not have two fields with the same name, not like that - PHP will overwrite all values received under the same parameter name with the last one, _unless_ you use square brackets in the name, such as `name="ref[]"` (or `name="ref[0]"`/`name="ref[foobar]"`, if you want to specify the index upfront) - then you will get an _array_ in `$_POST['ref']`

Comment: And btw., marking the field as readonly does not prevent the user from manipulating the value that gets send, for example using their dev tools. So if you need to receive this value unchanged at any cost, then you should rather keep it in the session to begin with.

Answer (score 5):

Disabled fields are not posted with the requests however you can add readonly attribute.

One other thing you can do is that disabling the field for the UI purpose and add a hidden input below with the same name and the value.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language, it highlights the data semantic, not the way the data is seen (e.g. using `<strong>` to make a text bold is a totally wrong way). So you should use a CSS-customized text container(`<div>` or `<span>` mostly) to encapsulate it and being btw read-only. Then, just like Adam abdul shakoor suggested, you may use an hidden input with the same value.
You should also consider using VueJS (already packaged within Laravel), its data-driven approach makes this kind of things trivial to keep container's and input's contents synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think? If you have a value that needs to be sent back, place it in the hidden input field. So you could create a fake field using css, maybe. But if you do not want to send any data, just to show it, you may simply not include the hidden input field with the value.